# Is there any hope to compute analytically $y=f(x)$ for which $g(x,y)=0$?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions, parametric-functions, multivalued

I have a two-variable function $g(x,y)$ with $0<x\leq\frac{\pi}2$ and $\frac32<y<5$. I am looking for $y=f(x)$ for which $g(x,y)=0$. Using `ContourPlot`

```
g[x_,y_]= -4 (-44 + 
     8 Abs[-2 (Sin[x/2 - (3 y)/2] - 
          3 Sin[x/2 + y/2]) (2 Sin[x/2 - (7 y)/2] + 
          Sin[(3 x)/2 - (5 y)/2] - 5 Sin[x/2 - (3 y)/2] - 
          3 Sin[(3 x)/2 - y/2] + 3 Sin[x/2 + y/2] + 
          6 Sin[x/2 + (5 y)/2])] + 
     4 Abs[6 + 9 Cos[2 x] + Cos[2 x - 4 y] - 4 Cos[x - 3 y] - 
        6 Cos[2 x - 2 y] + 8 Cos[x - y] - 10 Cos[2 y] + 
        12 Cos[x + y]] + -27 Cos[2 x] - Cos[2 x - 8 y] + 
     6 Cos[2 x - 6 y] - 11 Cos[2 x - 4 y] - 16 Cos[x - 3 y] + 
     12 Cos[2 x - 2 y] + 32 Cos[x - y] + 70 Cos[2 y] - 60 Cos[4 y] + 
     18 Cos[6 y] + 48 Cos[x + y] + 54 Cos[2 (x + y)] - 
     81 Cos[2 x + 4 y]);


p1 = ContourPlot[{g[x,y]== 0 }  , {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, {y, 3/2, 5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 90 , FrameLabel -> Automatic , AspectRatio -> 3];
p2 = ContourPlot[{y == \[Pi]/2, y == 3 \[Pi]/2}  , {x, 0, \[Pi]/
    2}, {y, 3/2, 5}, ContourStyle -> Red, FrameLabel -> Automatic , 
   AspectRatio -> 3];
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

I obtain this plot

[image]

> **My question.** Is there any hope to find the explicit expressions for the functions describing those blue curves in the form of $y=f(x)$? those red lines are $y=\frac{\pi}2$ and $3\frac{\pi}2$. I use `Solve[g[x,y]==0 ,y]` and `Reduce[g[x,y]==0 ,y]` and after an hour it is still running.

P.S.  More precisely, I want to compute the area enclosed between the red and blue curves analytically. (numerically, I can compute it using `NIntegrate[Boole[...]]`)

Comment: It does not seem to be a simple thing. Actually, there are no other ways than those you indicated. Further, even if these ways bring you to a solution after a long calculation, it will probably be cumbersome. What I would do in this case, is solve the problem numerically in several points. After that, I would try to fit the numerical solution with some simple analytical function.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Dealing numerically sounds complicated too; that long blue curve is a bit scary to be approximated numerically!

Comment: `Reduce[g[x, y] == 0 && 0 <= x <= \[Pi]/2, y, Reals]` actually does return something, but it's so big that there's no way you can realistically do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here my numerical solution (inspired by @AlexeiBoulbitch useful comment):

upper contour

```
contUP=cont = ContourPlot[{g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, {y, 3 , 5},PlotPoints -> 90, FrameLabel -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 3]
```

[image]

get the points

```
pi = contUP[[1, 1]][[1]];
```

points pi form a polygon, the enclosed area follows to

```
Area[Polygon[pi]]
(*0.76061*)
```

lower contour might be solved similarely (lower area gives 0.437233)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, it confirms the result I had obtained by  `NIntegrate` but it is still numeric' so, probably there is no hope to find analytic solutions.